What exactly is the purpose of MSBuild's RestorePackagesPath parameter?
In my build pipeline I first run restore as follows:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" 
/t:restore /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true /p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\NuGetPackages\NuGet.Config" "C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\SampleProject.sln" 

This restores ALL NuGet packages including for .NET and .NET Framework NuGet packages to C:\NuGetPackages. (I have a solution composed of .NET Framework Server and a .NET Web Client communicating via WCF)
Now I would like to build my solution and want to specify that it should use all the restored NuGet packages that now reside in C:\NugetPackages. I thus run the following command:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\SampleProject.sln" /property:Configuration=Debug /p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\NuGetPackages\NuGet.Config" /p:RestorePackagesPath="C:\NuGetPackages" -v:diag

And I get the following first error:

C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\Base\Base.csproj(483,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\build\EntityFramework.props.

Done executing task "Error" -- FAILED. (TaskId:144)

I now know that when I run my build stage, it's ALSO looking for packages in the C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\packages folder and not in JUST in my c:\NuGetPackages folder.
What's also interesting, in my msbuild output all mentions of NuGetPackagesRoot are the following:
NuGetPackageRoot = C:\NuGetPackages

So that begs the question, why is my 2nd build step even looking in the C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\packages folder? I don't specify this folder anywhere. I want it to ONLY look for packages in C:\NuGetPackages, not anywhere else.
As an aside, my C:\NuGetPackages\NuGet.Config file looks as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <disabledPackageSources>
        <add key="Microsoft and .NET" value="true" />
    </disabledPackageSources>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="telerik.com" value="https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <telerik.com>
            <add key="Username" value="SomeUserName@SomeDomain.com" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="SomePassword" />
        </telerik.com>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\NuGetPackages" />
        <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="C:\NuGetPackages" />
    </config>
</configuration>


RestorePackagesPath pointing where packages are restored to, usually c:\users\userName\.nuget. However, note that MSBuild can restore when <PackageReference> is used. But if you're using packages.config nuget.exe is responsible for restoring packages. And since you're using latter, this setting does nothing.
To actually restore packages, you need to issue /p:Restore. Your package location must match between proj files references and nuget.config to build successfully. I remember cases when it was helpful to copy nuget.exe into same folder as MSBuild. Usually, the nuget.exe is located in the same folder as solution, under .nuget, together with nuget.config.
Best that you can do is to convert your projects to use <PackageReference> and use default settings with /p:Restore and not use any other settings related to the nuget.
Make sure your solution is stored properly to relative paths
solution
  -- .nuget
  -- project1
  -- project2

Another thing - try to run your command from the solution dir. - "These settings collectively apply to any NuGet operation invoked from the command line or from Visual Studio, with settings that exist "closest" to a solution or the current folder taking precedence. If a command line tool is used on a project file, rather than a solution file, then the project directory is used as the "solution directory", which can lead to inconsistent behaviour when there is a NuGet.Config file in a subdirectory of the solution file."

So I just now discovered that it's looking for my NuGet packages in C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\packages, but WHY there? I explicitly state to use /p:RestorePackagePath="C:\NuGetPackages"! How can I tell msbuild to look for NuGet packages in C:\NuGetPackages?

I think you confuse /p:RestorePackagesPath with /p:RestoreConfigFile. The latter points to NuGet.config. And in my c:\NuGetPackages\NuGet.Config I specify: <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\NuGetPackages" />

@Marcin - see updated answer

Also, in my environment I have both, packages.config and package references. We add packages config folder to source control, so we don't need to rely on network to build. Build is not failing because of network interruptions and is not slower because of downloads, With package reference even better, They stay in the users folder even when you trash the branch. And multiple branches use packages from same location saving space on the disk. so you only have 1 download and no time wasted thereafter.

In my first build step I restore with the following command: msbuild /t:restore /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true /p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\NuGetPackages\NuGet.config" "C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\SampleProject.sln". It Restores ALL, both .NET Framework packages AND .NET packages. Now I'd like to build and use the restored packages from C:\NuGetPackages but instead it seems to look not in C:\NuGetPackages but inside of C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\packages. (At least for .NET Framework packages)

What you're doing makes no practical sense. What is the version of VS are you using? What is inside your packages.config? what is your proj/solution structure?

See revised question...

@Marcin do you have the hint path in your proj file for the package n question?

@Marcin if you're building solution with nuget.config in solution folder, with all configured properly, you don't need to run separate command to restore. You build and do /p:Restore all in one, with packages.config and ProjectReference projects. I suspect you have a hint issue. I don't understand why would you jump so many hoops

The reason we split Restore and Build into separate stages in our build pipeline is technical debt, but at least it let's me see that ALL packages are restored, both for .NET and .NET Framework projects. My issue is most probably like you mention that the <HintPath> is the culprit for my /p:RestorePackagesPath entry being ignored. I thus tried a solution at conditionally ignoring the <HintPath>s here. Perhaps you would know why that attempt is not working?

all these tags, or almost all, can be have with conditional attributes. That is not an issue, I had conditional references in few places. Still , I want to see how your reference looks like in the proj file @Marcin

I tried exactly that, including trying to add a condition directly on <HintPath>s. If you're interested in having a look, see here.
